# Get result from SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

I've got a MySQL query based on a database of ship information, this includes a field `ship_name` and the key `ship_id`.

I've written a query which uses the `current_ship_id` of the page, and finds the next ship based on the alphabetical list of `ship_names`.

This all works fine, HOWEVER, I'm trying to create a link using the below code in the 'IF' statement.

```
header("Location: shipinfo.php?ship_id=$next_ship_id");
```

What I don't know how to do is define the variable `next_ship_id`. I tried the line:

```
$next_ship_id = ($ship_id);
```

In theory, I want to get the result of the query `$sql` (of which I know there is only one result) and find it's `ship_id`.

How do I do that please?

```
$sql = "    SELECT ship_infomation.ship_id
              FROM   ship_infomation
        INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT ship_name 
                    FROM   ship_infomation
                   WHERE  ship_id = $current_ship_id
                   ) As current_ship
                ON ship_infomation.ship_name < current_ship.ship_name
          ORDER BY ship_infomation.ship_name ASC
             LIMIT 1";

// echo "<br /><br />$sql<br /><br />";
$ships = mysql_query($sql, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
$totalRows_ships = mysql_num_rows($ships);
$next_ship_id = ($ship_id);
if ($totalRows_ships = 1)
{
    header("Location: shipinfo.php?ship_id=$next_ship_id");
}
else
{
    // remain on current page  
}
```

Comment: you already have your ship.id don't you?

Comment: no the ship_id is currently based on current_ship_id, I want to know how to get next_ship_id, so pulling the ship_id from the result of the query

Comment: that gives me Current: 15 / Next: Array  when I start on ship_id=15 page

Comment: do i use that with echo Prix? Sorry v new to sql

Comment: like this `echo "Current: " . $current_ship_id . " / Next: " . $row_ships['ship_id'];` **OR** `echo "Current: " . $current_ship_id . " / Next: " . $row_ships['ship_infomation.ship_id'];`

Comment: I just get this 'Current: 15 / Next: '

Comment: @user2406993 `echo $totalRows_ships;` does it return 1 ? if not then your query is not working. if it does then run `print_r($row_ships);` to see how your array is.

Comment: I'm putting all you tell me in the if $total_ships = 1 brackets, so I assume it is running OK. Really appreciate your guidance with this as I am LOST

Comment: the priont_r($row_ships) just returns 'Array ( [ship_id] => 1 )'

Comment: So is id 1 the next ship id you expect ? that is what your query is returning as id.

Comment: no I'd be hoping for 16. At the moment all the ships are in alphabetical order matching the same numerical order of the ship_id. I'm basically trying to write a 'go to next ship' and 'go to previous ship' button. I could cheat and do 'current_ship_id+1' but this wouldn't take into account any latter additions, say for exaple adding a new ship called 'Sunday' would get the highest ID... make sense? Does that look like there's an error in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next ship use:

```
SELECT ship_id 
  FROM ship_infomation 
 WHERE ship_id = (SELECT min(ship_id) 
                    FROM ship_infomation 
                   WHERE ship_id > $current_ship_id) 
 LIMIT 1
```

For the previous ship use:

```
SELECT ship_id 
  FROM ship_infomation 
 WHERE ship_id = (SELECT max(ship_id) 
                    FROM ship_infomation 
                   WHERE ship_id < $current_ship_id) 
 LIMIT 1
```

And at your code change this:

```
$ships = mysql_query($sql, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
$totalRows_ships = mysql_num_rows($ships);
$next_ship_id = ($ship_id);
if ($totalRows_ships = 1)
{
    header("Location: shipinfo.php?ship_id=$next_ship_id");
}
else
{
    // remain on current page  
}
```

To this:

```
$ships = mysql_query($sql, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
$totalRows_ships = mysql_num_rows($ships);
if ($totalRows_ships = 1)
{
    header("Location: shipinfo.php?ship_id=" . $row['ship_id']);
}
else
{
    // remain on current page  
}
```

For the next and previous, on your code:

```
$go = isset($_GET['go']) ? $_GET['go'] : 'next';
if ($go == 'next')
    $sql = "SELECT ship_id FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id = (SELECT min(ship_id) FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id > ". mysql_real_escape_string($current_ship_id) . ") LIMIT 1";
else
    $sql = "SELECT ship_id FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id = (SELECT max(ship_id) FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id < ". mysql_real_escape_string($current_ship_id) . ") LIMIT 1";
```

And on your URL have it like this for the next ship:

```
http://mysite.com/ships.php?current_ship_id=15&go=next
```

And like this for the previous:

```
http://mysite.com/ships.php?current_ship_id=15&go=previous
```

If the go is not specified it will go to the previous ship by default.

---

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: I'll try all that - really appreciate your assistance on this warm Sunday. thanks

Comment: @user2406993 OK I have just updated my answer with query samples for Previous and Next ship before you try it, make sure u got the latest update.

Comment: hmmm, that takes me to the very last ship sadly

Comment: @user2406993 change it to `min` I was using `max` which will give u the last that was a typo see the above queries as I have them updated.

Comment: It works going forward - I could literally kiss you (if that wasn't a bit weird).

Comment: for going to the previous you use the 2nd query and for the next you use the first query.

Comment: It works going forward, I could literally kiss you (if that wasn't a bit weird. Very quick final question. This code is exectued from a page with 'Previous' and 'Next' links on - at the moment, both links cause the 'Next' action. I think what I need to do is add an if direction=next statement containing everything you've helped and then an else with the action for previous.. I think

Comment: @user2406993 could you [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17638967/edit) with an example of what you're saying ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks, sure I'll work it out, at the moment both buttons on the page go forward, but I'll work it out (I think) x

Comment: @user2406993 have updated it at the bottom with an example of how you could do it.